# Split character strings in column & make new rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. Column 2 has genes separated by `;` such as `A;B`, `A;B;C;D`. The number of these genes may range from 2 to many. I want to split the genes in pairs of 2 and put them into new rows. Importantly, I want all possible combinations of those genes (originally together) for creating the new rows. Of course, if there are only 2 genes to start with then nothing needs to be done. Also, I would like to maintain the values (text) in Column 1 for newly created rows. 
I did not try anything because I have no idea how to approach the problem.
Example input and my desired output are given below.
Any help or suggestions on how to tackle this will be highly appreciated. I do have some (limited) experience with tidyverse.
Thank you for your time.

```
input = data.frame(col1 = c("example1", "example2"), col2 = c("A;B", "A;B;C;D"))

output = data.frame(col1 = c("example1", 
                             "example2", 
                             "example2", 
                             "example2", 
                             "example2", 
                             "example2"), col2 = c("A;B",
                                                   "A;B", 
                                                   "A;C",
                                                   "A;D", 
                                                   "B;C", 
                                                   "B;D", 
                                                   "C;D"))
```

Comment: What happened to the `A;B` combination for the second row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

input %>%
  filter(grepl(";", col2)) %>%
  mutate(x = str_split(col2, ";") %>% map(~combn(., 2, paste0, collapse = ";"))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(-col2)

# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   col1 [2]
  col1     x    
  <fct>    <chr>
1 example1 A;B  
2 example2 A;B  
3 example2 A;C  
4 example2 A;D  
5 example2 B;C  
6 example2 B;D  
7 example2 C;D
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting error: `Error in combn(., 2, paste0, collapse = ";") : n < m`

Comment: You are right, there are cases with 1 gene. But then the other code did work (by removing those single-gene cases). I am happy to remove cases with 1 gene, because I am only interested in pairwise comparisons.

Comment: I see - have updated answer to include `filter` to remove such cases.

Comment: Thanks. It now works as expected. I am still getting slightly different results for the two solutions: 63530 rows for yours and 63542 for @Pasqui. Not a big problem though. Cheers!

Comment: I am accepting this solution because its blazing fast and a much smaller code !!!

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a helper function first (from your `input` I have turned `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`; if it's not an option for you, just add `as.character()` to the helper function):

```
char_comb <- function(aString) {

   str_split(aString, pattern = ';') %>% 
      unlist() %>% 
      combn(2, paste0, collapse = ";")
```

}

NB - to demonstrated the helper function with a minimal example run: `char_comb(aString = "A;B;C;D")`

And then:

```
map2(.x = input[['col1']], 
     .y = input[['col2']], .f = function(idx, cell) {
        

    if(nchar(cell) > 3) {
        
        res <- char_comb(cell)
        tibble(col1 = idx, col2 = res)
            
    } else {

        tibble(col1 = idx, col2 = cell)
        }
    }) %>% 
    bind_rows()

Result:
  col1     col2 
  <chr>    <chr>
1 example1 A;B  
2 example2 A;B  
3 example2 A;C  
4 example2 A;D  
5 example2 B;C  
6 example2 B;D  
7 example2 C;D
```

p.s. my solution includes also the "A;B"s. It will be trivial to exclude them in case.

#### EDIT: adding benchmarks.

From the comments it looks like @ip2018 is concerned about exec time.
Wrapping both solutions in a function ...

```
microbenchmark("pasqui" = res_fn(col1 = input[['col1']], col2 = input[['col2']]), 
               "H 1" = h1_res()
               )
```

Benchmark results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 pasqui 1.137418 1.198085  1.403278  1.297016  1.611183  2.310684   100  a 
    H 1 9.140376 9.811799 12.126555 10.730754 13.036842 45.186844   100   b
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked beautifully. Takes about ~2 secs to complete on my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution which computes everything inside a for loop, Not sure how it will compare to pasqui's answer in terms of processing time.

```
col1<-c()
col2<-c()

for(i in 1:nrow(input)){
 name<-input$col1[i]
 splt<-unlist(strsplit(input$col2[i],";"))

 #Generate Matrix of Pair-Wise Combinations
 combs<-sapply(splt, function(x) sapply(splt, function(y) paste(x,y, sep=";") ))

 #Limit to Unique Combinations
 uni_combinations<-combs[lower.tri(combs)] 

 #Save vector of names
 n<-length(uni_combinations)
 col1<-c(col1,rep(name,n))

 # Save vector of gene combinations
 col2<-c(col2, uni_combinations)
}

# Put results in data.frame()
result<-data.frame(col1=col1, col2 = col2)
result
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked beautifully too. Though, took about ~28 secs to complete on my MacBook Pro.